# Data written to USB to Serial adaptor differs from data received – regression in OS X 10.11.2

Tags: macos, usb

After I update to OS X 10.11.2, El-Capitan, from 10.11, my [Aten USB to Serial UC 232A](http://www.aten-usa.com/products/productItem.php?model_no=UC232A) no longer works properly.

When I send hexadecimal data, for example client send : `02 01 10 30 30 30 03 CB`, the server will receive `02 01 10 FF 82 8A 03 CB 00`. Server always receive different data even when I send same data twice. Somebody can help me? Thanks.

Note :

- I use MacBook Pro - Mid 2014
- I use CoolTerm to send data and the Adaptor is Aten USB to Serial UC 232A.

Comment: In addition to this question, please can you report this directly to Apple via [Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com). Every report helps!

Answer (score -2):

This explanation on how to install USB serial drivers works for me

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zuRukW7o0A

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.